# How to get the value from watch in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am sing React-hook-form `watch` to render component conditionally.

But I am not getting the current value to render but it shows in `console.log()`.

```js
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    mode: 'all',
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

 const watchShowCover = watch('cover');
 console.log('image', watchShowCover);
```

The image field is `cover`. On selecting the image I am able to see the
[image: imaeg]

But I am not able to get the properties for conditional rendering.

```js
     {!watchShowCover ? (
            <ImageField
              className="col-span-1"
              label="Cover Image"
              placeholderText="Series cover"
              registration={register('cover')}
              error={errors.cover?.message}
            />
          ) : (
            <p>
              Render the image {watchShowCover.name}
              <img src={watchShowCover.name} alt="" />
            </p>
          )}
```

[Example demo here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/modern-glitter-kpfvkx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[image]

Comment: Try `<img src={watchShowCover[0].name} alt="" />`

Comment: I am using TS, watchShowCover is a file. `watchShowCover[0].name` does not have that property